# Positioning CSS errors

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS code for a webpage I am developing using Django. 
The problem I am currently running into is that the width, left and margin-left within inputlabel and input area do not have an effect on the position.
inputlabel fits the content within it, as does input area.

Neither of the two seem to change no matter the values I change.

However, #id_description works as expected.

I'm new to CSS and am not 100% sure what it is I'm missing.

```
container {
    position: relative;
}    
inputlabel { 
    width: 200px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 1000px;  
}
inputarea {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#id_description { 
    resize: none; 
    width: 500px; 

} 
body { 

}
```

Comment: `inputlabel` and `inputarea` (and `container`) (TY) should either be classes (start with a dot) or IDs (start with a hash #). It will depend on your HTML which you have not provided.

Comment: ^ and `container`, I would suggest reading up on [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/css-coding-with-style/0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use next:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}    
.inputlabel { 
    width: 200px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 1000px;  
}
.inputarea {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Html code would be so:

```
<div class='container'>
```

or

```
<input class='inputlabel' ...>
```

Also you can use next:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}    
#inputlabel { 
    width: 200px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 1000px;  
}
#inputarea {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Code would be so:

```
<div id='container'>
```

or

```
<input id='inputlabel' ...>
```

So `#` before style name means you should link this style with tag via `id`. `.` symbol means you have to link this style with tag via `class`.

But: `body` part in your css code might be ok. You can use `body` or `input` names, so it will affect on all tags with such names.

There is an article where you can read about the difference between `id` and `class` styles: [click me](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 1):

you're missing '.' and '#'

if `container` is a `class`,then you need to use `.container`

if `container` is a `id`,then you need to use `#container`

Same applied for all.

Answer (score 0):

To define css for a class, use `.container{}`, `.inputlabel{}`, etc. You are missing the `.`'s